# Samples of using Skype API phone call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, skype, skype4com

Is there a good tutorial or example out there for initiating a Skype phone call through the API using C#/ASP.NET MVC3? I did some searching on the web but could not find info specific to initiating a call through the API.

Comment: did it help? how did you implement your requirement? It will be very nice of you, if you can kindly share something. I am also looking for something like an API to make video calls.